# How to find the connection type of a network from Wireshark trace?

Tags: wireshark, packet

I'm doing some analysis on a wireshark network trace. How to find the connection type of the underlying network? (eg: wireless)

Is it possible to obtain this information from packet analysis?

Thanks in advance.

Lasith.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily, as per the comments on [the same question on the Wireshark Q&A site](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/24442/how-to-find-the-connection-type-of-a-network-from-wireshark-trace).  Non-monitor-mode captures on Wi-Fi tend to look indistinguishable from Ethernet captures; you'd either have to look for protocols used by Wi-Fi devices (e.g., by access points) or look for something such as packet loss patterns that are more likely on Wi-Fi than Ethernet.  (I don't have any suggestions to make for either of those cases.)